Power automate breaks when running Excel Office Scripts - Bad Gateway
I have a flow that runs a series of Excel Office Scripts.
Sometimes, the flow runs and concludes without issues in 3 minutes.
Some other times, it runs within 10 minutes, without issues.
Some other times, it takes 30 minutes and breaks with the message: "Bad Gateway".
It is the same flow with the same scripts and the same data.
So, why is Power Automate so unreliable?

Maybe you've written a bad flow.
